# PyCharm won't print or return

Tags: python, pycharm

The code I am working with is following:

```
def fragmenten(bestand):


    bestand = open('fragmenten1n.txt', 'r')
    dic = {}

    for regel in bestand:
        regel = regel.strip("\n")
        for element in regel:
            if element != "-" and element != " ":
                dic[(regel.find(element) + 1)] = {element}

return(dic)
```

My problem here is that for some reason PyCharm won't return anything ( I would expect to get the dic in return). I tried working with print function but all PyCharm gives is

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

That is great and all but I like to see my solution too. Now I know my program gives a solution since when I enter my program on my school site I do get a solution. So maybe I am just working in the wrong window.

This is my current window:

[image: Screenshot of pycharm]

Does someone know how to change these settings? or is it something that goes wrong in my code ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you calling the function?

Comment: i just want to return the dictionary i made before the for-loop. (if that is what you mean ?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your function. Try adding the following code to the end of your file. Outside of the function.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
  fragmenten(bestand)
```

It is however very strange that you pass bestand as your parameter, since you declare it again in the beginning of your function. Try removing the parameter, and call the function without it.

Comment: this "strange" calling is because of the fact it is a school project my school program each time redefines "bestand" so it can be tested with different files.

Comment: If I add that it gives me following error :     If __name__ == "__main__":\
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Since idk this function I don't know if maybe is a typo or something else

Comment: `If __name__=="__main__":` it has to be exactly like that written

Comment: @Liberty Verleysen `If` should be `if`.

Comment: @coal that seems to make no diffrence